# Theming a new Panel Page

Tags: panels, theming

I think I am missing something really silly here. I am trying to learn theming in drupal. So I downloaded a "starter" theme called Genesis and installed it. This theme has a barebones header and footer. And in the middle the content area is split into left sidebar, main content and right sidebar.

I created a panel page with 'flexible' layout. It has only one region defined and inside it I placed a custom view I had created earlier. Now when I hit this panel page url, it shows up correctly, but inside the main content area of theme. I mean the header, footer, left and right sidebars are still visible.

My question is: By default do panel pages render inside main content area? How can I customize a panel page such that I can do away with the header, footer or sidebars if I want to?

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

> By default do panel pages render inside main content area?

No, Panels should 'takeover' the page based on your ctools page manager assignments.

See /admin/structure/pages to confirm you have the path set in page manager ("Pages").

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have set the path in page manager for my panel page to 'test-panel'. When I hit the url 'http://localhost/test-panel' I can view the newly created panel page. The only problem is that, as mentioned, before it shows up within the content area with the sidebars and header/footer...not sure what I am missing here..

Answer (score 0):

> By default do panel pages render inside main content area?

Yes, panel pages are output in the main content region.

Also, there's an option to disable all blocks/regions in your theme under the General settings for your Panel variant. This feature doesn't work for all themes though.